# Adding List Elements to a Multi-line String

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that automatically sets up a HTML file using information from a list I've generated. This chunk below is part of a multi-line string.

```
`"""...
<tr>
  <td>10</td>
  <th>"""+str(List_Data[9])+"""</th>
  <th>"""+str(Extra_Data[9])+"""</th>
</tr>
</table>
..."""`
```

Extra_Data is a list of number ratings, so Extra_Data[9] = 7.2. When I run the code I get the following error;

```
`<th>"""+str(Extra_Data[9])+"""</th>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to st`
```

I'm not sure how else I could get this to work since str(Extra_Data[9]) doesn't do the trick and this is the only way I can think to get all of my listed data to be apart of the HTML code efficiently. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This _should_ work. Are you sure you did not accidentally redefine `str`?

Comment: Also, did you get that exact error message? Because even if I trigger that sort of error, the wording is different for me, both for Python 2 and 3. I do, however, get a message like that when trying to concatenate a `str` to `list` (but not the other way around). And even if `str` did not do anything, `Extra_Data[9]` should be `float` and not `list`.

Comment: I'm certain I didn't accidentally redefine  str

Comment: And yes, I did get that exact error message. I agree that it is certainly strange to be getting this error message

Comment: Then please try to define a minimum example that reproduces that error, including `Extra_Data` etc. In fact, chances are that doing this, you will find the error yourself.

Comment: Are you using the back tick characters (`) in your code? Your code, without the back tick characters, works for me. Which version of Python are you using? FYI I'm on 2.7.15.

Comment: @B.Stewart If my answer solved your issue, please can you mark it as accepted? This will help others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: Yeah I'll mark it as accepted if I can get it to work for my thing. I'm having a hard time adapting it for my program. To answer your earlier comment, the back tick characters aren't apart of  my code. Since it worked for you otherwise my error must be somewhere else within the code. Python 3.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has the really handy string formatting method `.format()`, take a look [here](https://pyformat.info/). All you'd need to do is something along the lines of:

```
a = """
<tr>
  <td>10</td>
  <th>{0}</th>
  <th>{1}</th>
</tr>
</table>
""".format(List_Data[9], Extra_Data[9])

print a
```

The numbers in swirly brackets `{n}` are the placeholders for the argument at the nth index of the `.format()` function.

To take this one step further, you could iterate over your data lists to create each row programatically:

```
Table_Array = list()

for index, value in enumerate(List_Data):
    Table_Array.append("""
                       <tr>
                           <td>{0}</td>
                           <th>{1}</th>
                           <th>{2}</th>
                       </tr>
                       """.format(index, List_Data[index], Extra_Data[index])
```

Comment: While this should work, and is probably cleaner than OP's approach, OP's way should have worked, too, so chances are that the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: Agreed, it's an issue that needs more details and a repro to debug.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work for my string since it's creating HTML code, and HTML code often features curly brackets around formatting code. When I tried to adapt it, all the formatting gets in the way and makes it unusable for me.

Comment: How so? As in it wont be read as text for my HTML formatting? When I run your suggestion I get the following error; `""".format(index, List_Data[i], Extra_Data[i]))
KeyError: 'font-family'`

Comment: @B.Stewart I guess you could separate the string that contain inline-CSS and those that use the `format` method. But anyway, I doubt that this really solves the underlying issue of your code.

Comment: @B.Stewart I had a typo in my code, the `i`s are actually supposed to be `index`.

Answer (score 1):

So, in my crazy attempts to solve this issue. I changed the line to this;
`<th>"""+str(float(Extra_Data[9]))+"""</th>` and then it worked. I have no idea why so I changed it back to the original line and then it continued to work. I am so very confused as to why this has happened but as it stands now, my code works and it's the same as it did when it didn't work. I'm not sure why or how.